# "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" using canvas.on of Frabic.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this problem, Im using the Fabric.js to draw simple lines and forms, I need to get the Coordinates of the forms in pixels and save them in a string, Im using canvas.on to get them, but Im getting this error.
[image]
`

The canvas.on is not in a function.

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  X= options.e.layerX;
  Y= options.e.layerY;
});
```

Comment: Show us where canvas gets a value since the error says it is undefined.

Comment: I was able to solve it, the canvas was initialized in a function that I had not seen